# Unexpected behaviour of UIRefreshControl during use of UITableView reload data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using `UITableView` with `UIRefreshControl` in my `UIViewController`. When user pulls down the `UITableView`, `UIRefreshControl` it works fine. Problem occurs when the data is being fetched. After successful fetching i want `UIRefreshControl` to stop animate and reload data in the table view.

[Video related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Vjg.jpg)

The thing is that when I do it as below animation flickers, jumps and god know what else.

```
private func setupActions() {
    mainView.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fetchSurveys), for: .valueChanged)
}
@objc private func fetchSurveys() {
    viewModel.fetchSurveys(success: { [weak self] in
        self?.mainView.configureEmptyTableView(isHidden: false)
        self?.mainView.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self?.mainView.tableView.reloadData()
        }, failure: { [weak self] error in
            self?.mainView.configureEmptyTableView(with: "Unable to fetch surveys. Please try again.", isHidden: true)
            self?.mainView.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    })
}
```

I've tried many combinations of order of reloadData() and endRefreshing() and still it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: have 0.1 sec delay. once end refreshing nill out the property.

Comment: @karthik what? why should I make the property nil? using a delay isn't good also

Comment: dismissing view and indicator both happens on main. some rime it may leads to glitch bcoz of concurrent dismissals. investing a delay can give buffer time there. second ques, if you did nil out, the old reference also considered while dismissing. seems like multiple loaders